# Java runtime enviroment missing even when updated

Tags: java, exe, launch4j

So, i have been looking for the answer for this but i havent found anything, and i cant just ignore it
the thing is that i have created a windows applicaction on Eclipse, and it works on my pc, now i want it to run on my customers pc but when i try to open it there it pops up an error.

I have been trying on my computer, unistalling all java folders and subfolders and i just resolve the problem by installing the latest java version
So i updated my customers pc to the latest java version, now we both have 1.8.0_91-b14 jre after checking on the cmd

Im bundling this specific version on launch4j jre + a minimum jre 1.4.0 jsut in case and im still getting the same error:

> "This aplicattion was configured to bundled Java Runtime Enviroment
>   but the runtime is missing or corrupted"

any ideas?

on my program folder i dont add any jre folder, i guess its bundled inside the .exe am i wrong? i just have my exe, libraries(jars) and some config

it works on my pc so im pretty confused, and i found it difficult to know whats wrong